# How to make a hostname resolvable within a network without the need to add in hosts file for each computer

Tags: dns, hostname

I have setup GitHub enterprise in a server for on-premise usage. There it is having a private IP and has to be configured a hostname. It is showing

> "Ensure this domain is routable on your network."

If I map the hostname with IP address and add to my windows hosts file, then it's fine.

But I want a solution so that any people connecting to the office network has it resolved automatically without a manual entry in their host file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough users of your GitHub Enterprise Server that maintaining the hosts files is a pain, I'd suggest this happens when you have more than 10 users, then you will need to look at a DNS server for your Office Network. If you do not already have one then there are many options open to you depending on what your network looks like.